# SQL: add new rows for each distinct value

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table structure:

```
col1    col2    col3
id1   someval   time1
id1   someval   time1
id2   someval   time2
id2   someval   time2
id3   someval   time3
id3   someval   time3
```

I'm looking for a way to insert a new row for each distinct ID which only changes values in certain columns (column 2 in this case), but leaves every other column the same. I could do this by simply inserting it manually which wouldn't take long but I have the following issue with this:

1) I have a column with time values, this makes it particularly tricky because I'd be using excel to give me the "insert into" query and copying values from excel -> sql and sql -> excel seems to mess up time values

2) My actual table is much larger (over 500k rows) and I need to modify around 1000 of them... If I have a way to keep track of what I am changing this would be great.

The end result should be:

```
col1    col2    col3
id1   someval   time1
id1   someval   time1
id1   NEWVAL    time1
id2   someval   time2
id2   someval   time2
id2   NEWVAL    time2
id3   someval   time3
id3   someval   time3
id3   NEWVAL    time3
```

Any assistance would be great here

Comment: About sql -> excel -> sql, if you use a concatenate function on a datetime, it'll convert it to a serial date (number ~40,000) - it seems like it's messing up values, but you can use TEXT to convert it to a readable datetime for an insert - like: =TEXT(A1, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss AM/PM") - I use excel -> sql for these kinds of inserts all the time, because you're creating a log at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this maybe:

```
insert into your_table (col1, col2, col3)
select distinct col1, 'newval', col3
from your_table
```

Comment: @user33484 Since it worked, don't forget to ACCEPT the answer